# netcat: Listen to incoming connections through WAN

Tags: linux, portforwarding, gateway, netcat

Does **netcat** have the ability to listen on a port behind NAT?

Or maybe it can perform port-forwarding automatically through UPnP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netcat` can listen on a port on the machine that it runs on... so if your machine is behind a NAT, it can listen on a port behind a NAT and if port-forwarding is done correctly on the NAT box, your `netcat` process will be accessible from outside the NAT; `netcat` cannot do port forwarding but you could use something like `stunnel` for that.